# CSS animation slightly increases the page width

Tags: html, css

I have a page with 3 flip cards based on this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_flip_card). For some reason, during the flip animation, a scroll bar appears on the side of the page and then disappears when the animation is over. It causes the page content to shrink and expand for a second.

Is there a way to avoid it? It seems like the animation expands the page width by a couple of pixels.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an overflow: hidden on the Card-Container.
It will cut of overflowing content and therefore avoid a scrolling bar.
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/overflow